# to handle value which is not in dropdown list angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

we have dropdown list with range

0,0x0,0x1,1

we decided to remove 0x0 and 0x1 from range.

Question:
For already existing file with value 0x0 dropdown value is blank, i want to write a code where

- if value is 0x0 then dropdown selected value should be 0
- if value is 0x1 then dropdown selected value should be 1

please help!

Comment: you need to show some code demonstrating what you are working with.  Also, why would you not just remove the invalid options from the list?

Comment: Update your database and replace those 0x0 with 0, or whatever. Or in your controller after fetching the data if the value of X field is 0x0 replace it with 0

Comment: @yBrodsky I did same -[ in your controller after fetching the data if the value of X field is 0x0 replace it with 0] it worked!